# Import Java library groovy

Tags: java, groovy

i want to use a method defined in the apache.common.net library in my groovy-Script.

I first downloaded and included it in my config:

```
            this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///${currentDir}/lib/commons-net-3.3.jar"))
```

Afterwards i try to use it in my groovy-script like this (to make it clear: the import pimpim.* imports also the classLoader above):

```
    import pimpim.*

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*

def pm = PM.getInstance("test")


public class FileUploadDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
```

I also tried several annotations for the "import" like

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Y:\pimconsole\scripts\ftp.gy: 11: unable to resolve class FTPClient
 @ line 11, column 15.
       FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
```

What did i miss? Sorry, i am still new to groovy :/

Comment: (assuming you're running the script from the command line, instead of hacking the classloader, does `groovy -cp .;lib/commons-net-3.3.jar ftp.gy` work?

Comment: Hey Tim, that helps and it works! Thanks. Is it possible to somehow "embeed" that command into the script/config itself?

Comment: Added a couple of options below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you can add it to the classpath when you start up your script;

```
groovy -cp .;lib/commons-net-3.3.jar ftp.gy
```

Or, you can add a `@Grab` annotation to your script, and Groovy will download the dependency and add it to the classpath before running (but this can not work if your scripts are executed on a box with no access to maven);

```
@Grab('commons-net:commons-net:3.3')
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*

...rest of your script...
```

Or the classpath hacking route you have above *should* work if you try:

```
this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File("lib/commons-net-3.3.jar").toURL())
```

Comment: The classpath hacking route does not work and i don't have access to maven but the classpath definition in the start up works so i'll use this. Thanks!